# When I read this file, how can i read all the records

Tags: c, file, file-io

When I read the file it doesn't include the last record, so in this case Bill Biking does      not show up

Here is the `hobbies.dat` file:

```
Bob Running
Josh Swimming
Bill Biking
```

And here's the program's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[30];
    char hobby[30];

    char *filename = "hobbies.dat";
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File cannot open");
        perror("The following error has occured");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nName\tHobby\n\n");
        fscanf(fp, "%s%s", name, hobby);

        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            printf("%s\t%s\n", name, hobby);
            fscanf(fp, "%s%s", name, hobby);
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loop as follows:

```
...
else
{
   printf("\nName\tHobby\n\n");
   while (!feof(fp))
   {
      fscanf(fp, "%s%s", name, hobby);
      printf("%s\t%s\n", name, hobby);
   }
}
...
```

I changed this because you need to do your final print before you `fscanf` again and reach EOF.